# How can I compile/debug Visual Studio 2012 Win32 project with Direct8 dlls

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to Win32.

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DirectDrawCreateEx@16
>   referenced in function "int __cdecl DD_Init(int,int,int)"
>   (?DD_Init@@YAHHHH@Z)

showing when i trying to run a direct8 Win32 Project on Win7 VS2012(with directx 11 installed) , can i use direct8 dlls compile win32 project in vs2012?

Answer (score 3):

The version of DirectX you are trying to use is very old.  But I'm fairly sure it is still supported, I see DirectDrawCreateEx() still present in the latest Windows SDK, version 8 that is included with VS2012.  Do avoid installing that old SDK as recommended in the other answer, it won't know anything about VS2012 and may deploy heavily outdated components that may flub your machine.  DirectX was integrated in the Windows SDK a while ago.

Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies setting.  Add `ddraw.lib`

Comment: Thx, it's working fine on Win7 compiled in VS2012 with dx9, but besides add ddraw.lib in Additional Dependencies setting, Additional Librart Directories also need to be specified in General option of Linker if reference a dx Version differ with system.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the DirectX 8 SDK installed and set the right Project Paths:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w(v=vs.71).aspx
You have to set the x86 lib directory for a win32 project.
Good Luck